# Writing bootstrapped phylogenetic trees generated with Biopython to a file using Bio.Phylo.write()

Tags: tree, format, biopython, statistics-bootstrap, phylogeny

I have a problem exporting BioPython Tree objects (from `Bio.Phylo`) with bootstrap values. The trees are created directly within my BioPython script based on distance matrices.

The trees basically look good, but when I use the `Bio.Phylo.write()` function to export them to a file (Newick, NEXUS or phyloXML-format), the bootstrap-support values seem to get exported in a faulty format.

The tree topology can be displayed nicely e.g. with ITOL or Dendroscope, but the bootstrap-values can not be displayed.

Examples of tree objects and the resulting newick and phyloxml files are shown below. What can I do to export the trees with correct (readable) bootstrap values?

---

**Example:**

this is what the tree-objects look like in BioPython (example tree with 5 "species" named A-F):

```py
Tree(rooted=False)
    Clade(branch_length=0, confidence=100.0, name='Inner3')
        Clade(branch_length=-0.0791666666667, name='A')
        Clade(branch_length=0.0375, confidence=10.0, name='Inner2')
            Clade(branch_length=0.0625, name='C')
            Clade(branch_length=0.104166666667, confidence=40.0, name='Inner1')
                Clade(branch_length=-0.15, name='D')
                Clade(branch_length=0.15, name='B')
        Clade(branch_length=0.0791666666667, name='E')
```

when I export this to newick format (-->`Bio.Phylo.write(mytree,outfile,"newick")`), the file ends up like this:

```
(A:-0.07917,(C:0.06250,(D:-0.15000,B:0.15000)Inner140.00:0.10417)Inner210.00:0.03750,E:0.07917)Inner3100.00:0.00000;
```

As you can see, the confidence values get concatenated with the inner branch labels and thus unreadable (e.g. "Inner140.00" for name="Inner1" and confidence=40.0).

In phyloXML-format, the tree-files look like this:

```xml
<phyloxml xmlns="http://www.phyloxml.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.phyloxml.org http://www.phyloxml.org/1.10/phyloxml.xsd">  
<phylogeny rooted="false">
<clade>
  <name>Inner3</name>
  <branch_length>0</branch_length>
  <confidence type="unknown">100.0</confidence>
  <clade>
    <name>A</name>
    <branch_length>-0.0791666666667</branch_length>
  </clade>
  <clade>
    <name>Inner2</name>
    <branch_length>0.0375</branch_length>
    <confidence type="unknown">10.0</confidence>
    <clade>
      <name>C</name>
      <branch_length>0.0625</branch_length>
    </clade>
    <clade>
      <name>Inner1</name>
      <branch_length>0.104166666667</branch_length>
      <confidence type="unknown">40.0</confidence>
      <clade>
        <name>D</name>
        <branch_length>-0.15</branch_length>
      </clade>
      <clade>
        <name>B</name>
        <branch_length>0.15</branch_length>
      </clade>
    </clade>
  </clade>
  <clade>
    <name>E</name>
    <branch_length>0.0791666666667</branch_length>
  </clade>
</clade>
```

This looks much better, but the confidence values still aren't recognized by tree vizualization tools such as ITOL (possibly due to the confidence type="unknown" labels?)

What can I do? Modifying the final result files seems risky (what if I actually want leaf labels with keywords such as "inner"?)

Also, I would like to restrict myself to the BioPython modules, as adding additional external Python modules as dependencies makes the tool complicated to implement for cooperation partners.

Comment: Your PhyoXML is incomplete (missing XML tag and closing phylogeny and phyloxml tags), but once they are added I can reproduce the Newick output:

    $ python -c "from Bio import Phylo; Phylo.convert('internal_names.xml', 'phyloxml', '/dev/stdout', 'newick')"

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Newick writer. I've reported it here: https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/488

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind: Finally found a workaround!

For anyone with the same problem: 
You can Iterate through all the internal nodes of a BioPython tree object given by the command `tree.get_nonterminals()` and set the internal node names to `None`. 
Since this `tree.get_nonterminals()` only outputs the **internal** nodes (not the leaves) the leave-names remain untouched.

Example:

```
for node in example_tree.get_nonterminals():
    node.name = None
```

That should fix the output when writing to Newick Format!